# How to convert List<List<String>> to List<String> in java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a List of type <List> as below

```
private List<List<String>> strListOfList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
strListOfList = [[A], [B], [C, D, E, F, G], [H, I, J, K, L]]
```

I need to convert this to a List of String as below

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L]
```

Can someone help me how can i achieve this? I tried different solutions. But it is not working as expected.

Comment: `strListOfList.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: For future reference, this operation is often called flattening, so that might help your future searches. 

In general, I would recommend familiarizing yourself with Java's stream libraries. They're a concise and general way to describe data transformations. They compose much better than writing the loops by hand.